# How to install a mod for a videogame?

Tags: c++, windows

I have created a mod for Mafia 3 ( the videogame ). So I need to know where is the folder of this game on the pc that not is always the same.
How can I do ?

Comment: Get whoever wants to use your mod to tell the installer where it is?

Comment: This better belongs in either Gaming or superuser.com EDIT: I misunderstood. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your installer ask the user to specify where the game directory is, pretty common way to solve this problem